# javascript replace

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

i want to replace month name by number in array, but my script doesnt work.

```
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
arr = arr.replace(/Jan/g, "01");
}
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) { 
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/Jan/gi, "01"); 
}
```

Also... Shouldn't the line be:

```
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Also note..

/Jan/gi Not /Jan/g

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you need:

```
arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/Jan/g, "01");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = a[i].replace(/Jan/g, "01");
}
```